# Slow solution to project euler 25 using haskell

Tags: haskell, optimization, fibonacci

I am new to the Haskell language, and to learn I thought i would jump into some Project Euler. In [Project Euler 25](https://projecteuler.net/problem=25) we are tasked with doing the following:

**The 12th term, F12, is the first term to contain three digits.
What is the index of the first term in the Fibonacci sequence to contain 1000 digits?**

And this is my solution to the problem:

```hs
fibGen :: Int -> Int
fibGen 0 = 0
fibGen 1 = 1
fibGen n = fibGen (n-1) + fibGen (n-2)

stepper n
  | length (show ( fibGen n )) >= 1000 = n
  | otherwise = stepper n + 1
```

Here `n` is just the starting point of the sequence. But this approach is incredibly slow, it had run over an hour before I decided to try another approach. Then I found another solution which is the following:

```hs
fibs = 0:1:(zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs))
t = 10^999

problem_25 = length w
    where
      w = takeWhile (< t) fibs
```

And this is incredibly fast.

So my question is what is wrong in the first approach that is making it so slow.

Comment: As an aside, while it wasn't what you were asking if you wanted to write an efficient recursive definition you could try something like `fibs = fibs' 0 1 where fibs' x y = y : fibs' y (x + y)`; This is more or less the same as the `zipWith` version but might be a bit easier to understand.

Comment: There is another solution that is completely different from this one. Note that `fib n = round $ phi ^ n / sqrt 5 where phi = (1 + sqrt 5)/2`. With some algebra, you can turn this into a formula for `n`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So my question is what is wrong in the first approach that is making it so slow.

Your first approach has an infinite loop in the difinition of `stepper`, but nevertheless, even if there was no infinite loop it would take a considerable amount of time, due to the exponential branching strategy.

---

Your first approach results in exponential recursion. Indeed, except for the two base cases, all other cases will result in two extra calls:

```
fibGen :: Int -> Int
fibGen 0 = 0
fibGen 1 = 1
fibGen n = fibGen (n-1) + fibGen (n-2)
```

So this means that for `fibGen 5` for example, we will evaluate this as:

```
fibGen 5
  - fibGen 4
    - fibGen 3
      - fibGen 2
        - fibGen 1
        - fibGen 0
      - fibGen 1
    - fibGen 2
      - fibGen 1
      - fibGen 0
  - fibGen 3
    - fibGen 2
      - fibGen 1
      - fibGen 0
    - fibGen 1
```

So in order to calculate `fibGen 5`, we thus will make a total of 15 calls. One for `fibGen 4`, two for `fibGen 3`, three for `fibGen 2`, five for `fibGen 1`, and three for `fibGen 0`.

Each time we increment `n`, we will almost double the amount of calls. It is clear that for a large `n`, the number of calls is that huge that a modern machine can still not process it.

Furthermore your `stepper` function is defined as an infinite loop. Indeed, a more verbose variant of your function is:

```
stepper n
  | length (show ( fibGen n )) >= 1000 = n
  | otherwise = (stepper n) + 1
```

So that means that if you calculate `stepper n`, and the constraint fails, you call `stepper n` again, and you will later add `1` to that result, but you thus get stuck in an infinite loop.

You can fix this by adding parenthesis:

```
stepper n
  | length (show ( fibGen n )) >= 1000 = n
  | otherwise = stepper (n + 1)
```

Now eventually the program will terminate, but it will take a lot of time, due to the branching in the recursive definition. Note that each time you call `fibGen`, it will again branch, so that means that even if we fix the infinite loop, if we have called `fibGen 5`, then if we later call `fibGen 6`, we will do all the work again to calculate `fibGen 5` to calculate `fibGen 6`. We thus do not use memoization here.

---

Your second fibonacci program on the other hand generates a list, and it reuses the results in the list. `fib` will thus evaluate as:

```
   0 : 1 : zipWith …
-> 0 : 1 : 1 : zipWith …
-> 0 : 1 : 1 : 2 : zipWith …
-> 0 : 1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : zipWith …
-> 0 : 1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : 5 : zipWith …
```

So this will not suffer from branching, since it *reuses* results that are already in the list.

Comment: Also `stepper` function calls `fibGen` at every recursion call. So `stepper 5` will call `fibGen 5` in the first guard, and then call `stepper 6` which will call `fibGen 6` without memoizing `fibGen 5` which is needed for `fibGen 6`. So is not only the exponential branches in `fibGen` but also all duplicate computation in `stepper`

Comment: @Shadesfear Can read up on the topic of memoization for more.

Comment: Thanks guy for the answer and comments, this is exactly what i needed! It's gonna be something I will think about in the future